# bash xargs -I% using its argument,

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xargs

I have this bash code:

```
ip=$1    
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${ip} << EOF    
jps | grep server.* | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -L1 -I% jmap -histo % > server-%-$ip-histo.out   
EOF
```

How to include the pid, in the file name,  in case of multi server instances on this box.

currently files are written as: `server-%-127.0.0.1-heap.out`

and not:  `server-xxxx-127.0.0.1-histo.out`

Comment: Do you realize that the `%` only has a meaning for the `xargs` command? In other words, do you know that the piece of code `> server-%-$ip-histo.out` is out of the scope of the `xargs` command?

Comment: Do you hope us to know the format of the input of the `xargs` command? Please, post examples of the text through the last pipe. Where is the pid found? i.e., what command does provide that pid: either `jps` or `jmap`?

Comment: ok so how to make the  > server-%-$ip-histo.out  bit part of the xargs scope,  so that the % can be replaces ?  possible putting ' around the lot'

Comment: It is not possible that. Before the `xargs` is executed, i.e. before the `%` may have any value, the shell takes the value `server-%-$ip-histo.out` and creates just ***ONE*** file with that name in order to store any output from `xargs` command.

Comment: The best way would be run a loop to save each value of `%` in a shell variable (let's say `myvar`), and execute the command line `jmap -histo "${myvar}" > server-"${myvar}-$ip"-histo.out`. But that may arise a new problem because you are using a here-document.

Comment: Use `sh -c 'jmap -histo "$1" > server-"$1-"'"$ip"'"-histo.out' -` as the `xargs` command? (Assuming I got those quotes right.)

Answer (score 0):

> How to include the pid, in the file name, in case of multi server
>   instances on this box.

Replace

```
xargs -L1 -I% jmap -histo % > server-%-$ip-histo.out
```

with

```
while read pid; do jmap -histo \$pid >server-\$pid-$ip-histo.out; done
```